# Integrity constraint violation laravel 9

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I am using Laravel 9 to set up my migrations but I keep getting this error  `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` I have looked this up and I'm very confused as my user_id in table urls does reference the id column on the users table?

I have also ensured that I have protected fillable for the `user_id` in my url.php model which I saw as an answer to a similar question.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('full_url');
            $table->string('short_url')->unique();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: share image of your migration folder. is your `urls` migration running before `users` migration ?

Comment: No, my users migration is first and the urls migration is last.

Comment: try this `$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();` make the foreign key nullable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are one of the mechanisms used to ensure data integrity. In this case, it means that the foreign key you're about to insert must have a correspondence within the associated foreign table.

Let me give an example. Let's say you have a posts table that has a `user_id` foreign key.
Then in your `users` table, you have the following ids: `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.
If you try to insert/update a post, the `user_id` provided must exist within the `users` table. So that means that if you tried to insert a new post that has a `user_id` of `7`, it would fail because there's no `id` of `7` in the `users` table.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, i added a record in my database with a `user_id` of 1 and then tried again and it worked.